# Volley error-UnsupportedOperationException when making json request

Tags: android

When I use Volley Library on
Android 5.1 all works fine.  But
when I run on 6.0 I got unsupported operation exception.
What can be the reason?

```
JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,

        url, null,

        new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {


        @Override

        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

        Log.e(TAG, response.toString());

        try {

        String apiNum = response.getString("apiNum");

        switch (apiNum){

        case "1":

        Log.e(TAG, "CASE 1");

        break;

        case "2":

        Log.e(TAG, "CASE 2");

        prefs.edit().putString("id", id.getText().toString())

        .putString("secret", password.getText().toString()).commit();

        listener.onRegister("success");

        break;

        case "-1":

        Log.e(TAG, "CASE -1");

        listener.onRegister("not_exists");

        break;

        default:

        listener.onRegister("error");

        Log.e(TAG, "DEFAULT");

        break;

        }

        } catch (JSONException e) {

        showAlert(getActivity(),

        "JSONException,"+"MEggase="+e.getMessage()+"Cause:"+e.getCause());

        e.printStackTrace();

        }

        pDialog.hide();

        }

        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override

        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

        Log.e(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());

        showAlert(getActivity(), "VolleyError,  

        "+"MEggase="+error.getMessage()+"Cause:"+error.getCause());

        pDialog.hide();

        }

        } );

        // Adding request to request queue

        try{

            AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonObjReq, tag_json_arry);

        } catch (Exception e){

            showAlert(getActivity(), "AddToRequestQueue Error");

        }
```

Comment: please post the error logs, if any.

Comment: Please take the time to learn to format your code. The `{}` button can be used after you highlight all the code.

Answer (score 0):

**Solved**
*The problem was in permissions. When I've added request for permissions app become to work without errors.*